# Could I use puppeteer page.pdf in normal web browser page?

Tags: javascript, pdf, puppeteer, html2canvas, html2pdf

I found the performance of puppeteer page.pdf is excellent against html2canvas+jspdf. So I wonder if I could get the `page.pdf` out of puppeteer, and use it in normal html page.
Thanks.